# How to create regex with following conditions?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regexp for US dollar validation using regexp in JavaScript.

```
/^\$?\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*\.?(\d+)?$/
```

but this doesn't work for 
`$.01` which is greater than 0 (as dollar sign is optional) and valid amount.
requirements are-

```
1.$2000
2.2000
3.$2000.00
4.$2,000
5.2000.00
6.2,000.00
7.$.04
```

Please suggest some changes in my current regexp.

Thanks
John

FOUND SOLUTION::--

```
^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$
```

Comment: You already seem to know how to indicate optional symbols. All you have to do is mark everything before `.` as optional.

Comment: Just use `\d{0,3}` instead of `\d{1,3}` it will match numbers form 0 to 3. So the whole regex will be `/^\$?\d{0,3}(,?\d{3})*\.?(\d+)?$/`

Comment: I don't understand why you are limiting the first `\d` to 1-3 characters, it should make your 3rd example fail

Comment: @jcubic but this will also validate as true to number $1000055,555.00

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't simply ignore all commas? They serve to make a number more readable to humans, but they have no meaning to computers. If you filter out commas first, then your regex becomes very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
^\$?(?=.)(?:\d{1,3})?(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/0qQBwTRMOl

Just remember to make digits before dot optional match and that enforces use of positive lookahead to make sure there is at least one digit after optional `$` sign.

**Here is a non-regex based solution to validate currency (USD):**

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en-US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
#$num = "1.234.567,89 $";
$num = "$.04";

var_dump($fmt->parseCurrency($num, $curr)); // returns float value: float(0.04)
var_dump($curr); // returns string representing currency: string(3) "USD"
```

Comment: but what about this number $1000055,555.00 this is actually invalid but regex will give it as true number.And this amount too $,000.00

Comment: That problem would be there with our original javascript regex as well.

Comment: I have just use yours regex and its not working with above amounts. :(

Comment: Did you see the demo?

Comment: Yes I saw and tested with above mentioned examples too.

Comment: Then you can see clearly that it worked with all of your example values.

Comment: best solution ^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$

Comment: I have edited my answer to also include a non-regex solution, btw even `NumberFormatter::parseCurrency` considers `$1000055,555.00` a valid number (which may or may not be right answer though).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern:

```
\$?(?:\.\d+|(?:\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d+)?)
```